# React + Firebase: error: ERROR Firebase Storage: No default bucket found

Tags: javascript, firebase

[![Estimadas/os!!!] Estoy aprendiendo React... Estoy utilizando VSC y Firebase... Me tira este error que muestro en la foto y no sé cómo resolverlo. Me dan una mano??? Gracias!!!

Dejo el repo por si lo quieren chusmear. Desde ya muchas gracias!!![image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.